# Problems with POST and cookies

Tags: php, asp-classic, session-cookies

I have a PHP script with cURL that does a POST request to an ASP file (not mine, so I can't change it).

I have set a Cookie (`ASPSESSIONID`) that I have received from Echo (an HTTP POST app for Mac) and used it in my code, but when I change my POST variables it still returns the same data as before, but when I make the POST using Echo (with the same Cookie) it works, and receives new data. When I now make the same request with my script it works also! How can I do this without Echo?

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Bgnm=3Ve&rst=$rst");  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Cookie: ASPSESSIONIDAACQRCDD=LAODBMKAPLDAJNILIKFGFPFP'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The normal HTML Form (fully working):

```
<form method="post" target="rechts"> 
<p align="center"> 
<br>Kies een basisgroep:<br>
<select name="Bgnm">
<option>1a</option><option>1b</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>Kies een roostersoort:<br>
<select name="rst">
<option selected="">Basisrooster</option>
<option>Rooster deze week</option>
<option>Rooster volgende week</option> 
</select>
<br><br>en druk op deze knop:
<br>
<input type="submit" value="toon lessen en lijst">
</p>
</form>
```

My setup in Echo:
[Echo setup (image)](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/4479/fotovz.png)

Comment: It's hard do tell without code, so please show us what you do, especially `but when I let Echo make the POST ` part. Debugging it, sending request to your server is good idea too.

Comment: try to use cookie file instead of setting it by yourself

Comment: The cookie name you mention in your post is different to the name of the cookie you're setting in the code; does that have any significance?

Comment: What do you mean? When I not change my (POST) variables it works. But when I change it the ASP stays returning the data with the old variables. I don't know how to fix that!

Comment: I added the HTML Form that is previously used, that works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

My bad! I made my request to the wrong URL. Thanks for helping anyway!